# AspectJ pointcut for AsyncTask in android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, aspectj

I am trying to have details of Http calls made in android app. I have my SDK embedded in app.

The app makes use of AsyncTask and HttpURLConnection to make http calls.

Hence I am thinking it will be great if I could intercept  each execution of AsyncTask

I tried below PointCuts

```
execution(* *.doInBackground(..))
execution(* *.executeOnExecutor(..))
```

but the advice not getting executed. 
I do not wish to use name of class which extends AsyncTask in my pointcut as that will limit my SDK to particular app. I want generic point cut like @onCreate which works for all android apps. 
What should be correct PointCut to intercept asyncTasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
execution(* AsyncTask+.doInBackground(..))
execution(* AsyncTask+.executeOnExecutor(..))
```

where `AsyncTask+` means the class and all of its subclasses. But be careful, the pointcut will only work on the classes under the control of your aspect weaver, not on others outside of it.